# is it possible to get the weeknumbers a an array in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

In fullcalendar it is possible to show the weeknumbers for a month: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/weekNumberCalculation/ and http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/weekNumbers/.

But is there some way to get the weeknumbers as a range for use in my javascript ?

/* UPDATE: NOW WITH A POSSIBLE SOLUTION */

thanks @Cerbrus for not letting me get by it so easy :-)

I came up with a solution by using moment-range (https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-range) and the uniq-function from underscorejs (http://underscorejs.org/#uniq). 
I have highlighted the important part below and my entire solution can be seen at this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/pj56Qu5f5hDMJ86S4mQx?p=preview

```
            viewRender: function (view, element) {
              console.log(view.start.format());
              console.log(view.end.format());
              var dayRange=moment().range(view.start,view.end);
              var weekRange=[];
              dayRange.by('days', function(moment) {
                  console.log(moment.format()+" "+moment.isoWeek());
                  weekRange.push(moment.isoWeek());
              });
             weekRange=_.uniq(weekRange);
             console.log(weekRange); 
           }
```

Based on the above I would like to change my question a bit and ask whether the above is an efficient solution or if it could be done better ?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: not sure what you are trying to convey, can you be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be more efficient. And it doesn't require a bunch of additional libraries.

Start with the start date and just add a week every iteration.

```
viewRender: function (view, element) {
    var weekNumbers = [];
    for (var m = view.start; m.isBefore(view.end); m.add(1,'week')){
        weekNumbers.push((m.isoWeek()%52)+1); //+1 to match FC's numbering.
        // %52 is used to correct for weird behaviour around the newyear.
    }
    console.log(weekNumbers);
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZJakuwwFnBklL5EddHI0?p=preview)